# Car hire in France without credit card or driver's license

Tags: france, car-rentals, payment-cards, driving-licenses, lost-documents

I am travelling to France tomorrow, where I have already booked a hire car, but my purse, containing credit cards and UK driver's license, has been stolen. I have debit cards with plenty of money, and my passport, so there is no issue of identity.

Is there a way I can get some proof that I do have a driver's licence (there must be a database of registered drivers somewhere at the DVLA [UK Driver and Vehicle Licensing Authority])?

Can I hire a car without a credit card as "insurance"?

Comment: What is a DVLA?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai https://www.google.com/search?q=DVLA&btnI=

Comment: Most french cards are actually debit card, so that's what the renting company is expecting. It is usually mandatory to show your driving license when you pick up the car, so not having it will probably be an issue. Can you get a proof of stolen driving license from the police department ?

Comment: You should also consider what to do if you succeed in getting the car, but then get controlled by the police without a driving licence.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you must have solved your problem since but the only solution for you would have been not to go through a car rental agency but through an individual in this situation.

I know numbers of my colleagues who have their papers in order rent through websites like "leboncoin" or "PAP" and the owner of the car which is an individual would just require identification papers but not necessarly a drivers licence. And for paying cash would have worked with an additional security deposit in cash as well.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please note that this site is not a forum but just questions and answers. Thus, I have removed the irrelevant part from your answer, which is considered clutter.

Comment: @Jan Sorry about that, I am not very familiar with the website yet..